# What is the problem with mapPut ? I cannot find the problem

Tags: c, list

map contains   - returns whether or not a key exists inside the map.

mapPut - Gives a specific key a given value and adding it to the map by order, if the key exists, the value is overridden.
  mapRemove   - Removes a pair of (key, data) elements for which the key matches a given element (by the key compare function).

mapGetFirst    - Sets the internal iterator to the first key in the map,    and returns it.

```
MapKeyElement mapGetFirst(Map map){
if(map == NULL){
    return NULL;
}
if (map->head == NULL){
    return NULL;
}
map->iterator = map->head;
return (map->copyMapKeyElements(map->iterator->key));
}
```

mapGetNext    - Advances the internal iterator to the next key and 
    returns it.

```
MapKeyElement mapGetNext(Map map){

if(map == NULL){
    return NULL;
}

if((map->iterator->next)== NULL) {
    return NULL;
}
map->iterator = map->iterator->next;
return (map->copyMapKeyElements(map->iterator->key));
} 

typedef struct MapElements_t{

   MapDataElement data;
   MapKeyElement key;
   struct MapElements_t* next;
 } *MapElements;

struct Map_t{
   copyMapDataElements copyMapDataElements;
   copyMapKeyElements copyMapKeyElements;
   freeMapDataElements freeMapDataElements;
   freeMapKeyElements freeMapKeyElements;
   compareMapKeyElements compareMapKeyElements;
   MapElements head;
   MapElements iterator;
 };

  /* ...... */

MapResult mapPut(Map map, MapKeyElement keyElement, MapDataElement dataElement) {

    if ((map == NULL) || (keyElement == NULL) || (dataElement == NULL)) {
        return MAP_NULL_ARGUMENT;
    }
    if (mapContains(map, keyElement)) {
        mapRemove(map, keyElement);
    }
    MapElements new_map_element = malloc(sizeof(new_map_element));
    if (new_map_element == NULL) {
        return MAP_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
    }
    new_map_element->data = dataElement;
    new_map_element->key = keyElement;
    new_map_element->next = NULL;

    if(map->head == NULL){
        map->head = new_map_element;
        map->iterator = map->head;
        return MAP_SUCCESS;
    }

    mapGetFirst(map);
    if (map->compareMapKeyElements(keyElement, map->iterator->key) < 0){
        new_map_element->next = map->iterator;
        map->head = new_map_element;
        return MAP_SUCCESS;
    }

    while(map->iterator->next != NULL) {
        if (map->compareMapKeyElements(keyElement, map->iterator->next->key) < 0) {
            new_map_element->next = map->iterator->next;
            map->iterator = new_map_element;
            return MAP_SUCCESS;
        }
        mapGetNext(map);
    }

    map->iterator->next = new_map_element;
    return MAP_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: How do you call it? What goes wrong?

Comment: Pretend like there are people that would truly be interested in helping.  Then consider what information would be needed to help them help you.  Little things, like a _[simplified compilable example of the problem code section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)_.  A statement explaining what you expect, and what you are seeing.  You might be surprised at the response.

Comment: I call it: Map map = mapCreate(copyDataChar, copyKeyInt, freeChar, freeInt,
                        compareInts);
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; ++i) {
        char j = (char) i;
        ++j;
        mapPut(map, &i, &j) ;
        MAP_FOREACH(int*, itera, map) { // * Macro for iterating over a map.
            printf("\n%d", *itera);
        } ---------- the result: 3 3 but it must print 1 2 3 (the key value)

Answer (score 1):

You have typedefs that include a pointer, such as `typedef struct MapElements_t{...} *MapElements;` which makes the type `MapElements` a pointer.

**This is discouraged** and for the following reason:

When you do

```
MapElements new_map_element = malloc(sizeof(new_map_element));
```

you are allocating the size of a pointer, not the size of the thing pointed to. In your case you should do:

```
MapElements new_map_element = malloc(sizeof(*new_map_element));
```

but preferably you would do:

```
typedef struct MapElements_t
{
    //...
   struct MapElements_t* next;
} MapElements;
```

so you make a variable that is a pointer to the thing have explicitly the `*`.

```
MapElements *new_map_element = malloc(sizeof(*new_map_element));
```

Comment: I suggest you take a debugger to step through the function to check, for all relevant cases, if it behaves as intended.

Answer (score 0):

The fault was here; I have to replace this code:

```
new_map_element->data = dataElement;
new_map_element->key = keyElement;
```

with this code:

```
new_map_element->data = map->copyMapDataElements(dataElement);
new_map_element->key = map->copyMapKeyElements(keyElement);
```